# Powershell help, how can I combine text files in a directory to one file?

Tags: sql-server, powershell, batch-file, sqlcommand

I'm new to powershell. I'm trying to convert some of our database scripts to powershell scripts.  One thing we do in our script currently (DOS BATCH FILE) is use the Type command...

```
@ECHO OFF

DEL *.sql 1>NUL 2>&1

TYPE ..\db\database\TuscanyProfileDB.sql > CreateDB.sql
TYPE ..\db\tbls\*.sql > CreateTables.sql
TYPE ..\db\foreignKeys\*.sql > CreateForeignKeys.sql
TYPE ..\db\indexes\*.sql > CreateIndexes.sql
TYPE ..\db\sprocs\*.sql > CreateSprocs.sql
```

It basically goes into the specified folder, and concatenates all the files with the `.sql` file extension and combines them into a new file.

My question is how can I do this in powershell?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
Remove-Item *.sql

Get-Content ..\db\database\TuscanyProfileDB.sql | Add-Content CreateDB.sql
Get-Content ..\db\tbls\*.sql | Add-Content CreateTables.sql
Get-Content ..\db\foreignKeys\*.sql | Add-Content CreateForeignKeys.sql
Get-Content ..\db\indexes\*.sql | Add-Content CreateIndexes.sql
Get-Content ..\db\sprocs\*.sql | Add-Content CreateSprocs.sql
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's what I use, adapted from [here](https://sqlserverpowershell.com/2011/10/20/powershell-script-to-check-for-low-drive-space-2/).

In my case I tend to have many directories, each one has many SQL files and I want to create a separate merged SQL file for each directory. I only want to merge the files that are prefixed with a number (e.g. `001_blah.sql`) and my merged file gets named upgrade_{DIRECTORY}.sql (e.g. `merged_1370_to_1380.sql`).

I put my `merge_sql_files.ps1` file in the parent directory and I put a `merge.bat` file in each of the directories with the SQL files.

`merge.bat` file looks like this

```
@ECHO OFF
SET PsFile=merge_sql_files.ps1
SET ThisScriptsDirectory=%~dp0
SET PowerShellScriptPath=%ThisScriptsDirectory%..\%PsFile%

PowerShell -NoProfile -ExecutionPolicy Bypass -Command "& '%PowerShellScriptPath%'";
```

`merge_sql_files.ps1` looks like this:

```
# Script to merge SQL files together. 
# Takes all the SQL files that start with a number and concats 
# them together, putting a line with "GO" in betweeen each one. 
# The output is saved as upgrade_[DirectoryName].sql, e.g. 
# 'upgrade_1370_to_1380.sql'. 
#
# This script should be run from the folder with the sql files, 
# e.g. put a merge.bat file in the folder that runs this ps1 script.

 
$path = (Resolve-Path .\).Path
$dirName = (get-item $path).Name
$outFile = "${path}\upgrade_${dirName}.sql"
 
if((Test-Path $outFile) -eq $true) {Remove-Item -Path $outFile -Force}
 
# Get all the SQL files that start with a number. Sort them 
$files = Get-ChildItem -LiteralPath $path -Include "*.sql" | where {$_.Name -match "^[0-9]" } | Sort-Object -Property Name
 
New-Item -ItemType file -Path $outFile -Force | Out-Null
 
foreach($file in $files)
{
    Write-Host "Appending file $file..." -ForegroundColor Gray
    $content = Get-Content -Path $file.FullName
    Add-Content -Path $outFile "----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------"
    Add-Content -Path $outFile "--      $File"
    Add-Content -Path $outFile "----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------"
    Add-Content -Path $outFile $content
    Add-Content -Path $outFile "GO`r`n"
}
 
Write-Host "Completed file $outFile" -ForegroundColor DarkGreen

# If running in the console, wait for input before closing.
if ($Host.Name -eq "ConsoleHost")
{
    Write-Host "Press any key to continue..."
    $Host.UI.RawUI.FlushInputBuffer()   # Make sure buffered input doesn't "press a key" and skip the ReadKey().
    $Host.UI.RawUI.ReadKey("NoEcho,IncludeKeyUp") > $null
}
```